# ImportError: No module named pymongo

Tags: python, ansible, pymongo

I'm trying to install [PyMongo](http://api.mongodb.com/python/current/) Python package with pip. It is required by [Ansible mongodb_user module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/mongodb_user_module.html).

I'm installing pip and pymongo with following Ansible script:

```
- hosts: tag_Name_Development
  become: true
  remote_user: user
  tasks:
    - name: install python tools
      yum: name={{ item }} state=latest
      with_items:
        - gcc
        - python-devel
        - python-setuptools
        - python-pip

    - name: install pymongo
      pip: name=pymongo state=latest

    - name: add admin user to mongo
      mongodb_user:
        login_port: 27017
        database: admin
        name: admin
        password: "{{ mongodb.admin_pass }}"
        roles: userAdminAnyDatabase
        state: present
```

After successful installation of tools I get following Ansible error.

`FAILED! => {"changed": false, "failed": true, "msg": "the python pymongo module is required"}`

On server where `pymongo` is installed I get

```
$ python -c "import pymongo"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named pymongo
```

Other relevant info `pip freeze` and `pip list`

```
$ python-pip freeze
backports.ssl-match-hostname==3.4.0.2
ordereddict==1.2
pymongo==3.3.0

$ python-pip list
backports.ssl-match-hostname (3.4.0.2)
ordereddict (1.2)
pip (6.1.1)
pymongo (3.3.0)
setuptools (12.2)
```

And loaded paths

```
$ python
Python 2.7.10 (default, Jul 20 2016, 20:53:27)
[GCC 4.8.3 20140911 (Red Hat 4.8.3-9)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import sys
>>> sys.path
['', '/usr/lib64/python27.zip', '/usr/lib64/python2.7', '/usr/lib64/python2.7/plat-linux2', '/usr/lib64/python2.7/lib-tk', '/usr/lib64/python2.7/lib-old', '/usr/lib64/python2.7/lib-dynload', '/usr/local/lib64/python2.7/site-packages', '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages', '/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages', '/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages', '/usr/lib64/python2.7/dist-packages', '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages']
```

There are many other questions related to this problem, but none of those have helped. I do not have `bson` installed and I'm not using any virtual envs.

Answer (score 0):

It turned out that I have two versions of python installed (2.6 and 2.7). Even though default is 2.7, my Ansible script installed `pymongo` under 2.6 folder `/usr/local/lib64/python2.6/site-packages`

I found that out by running `$ python-pip show pymongo` and `$ python2.6 -c "import pymongo"` works as expected.

I changed my Ansible script to install `python27-pip` instead of `python-pip` and it started to work nicely.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem. I solved it by appending PIP installation directory to PYTHON_PATH and changing permission of PIP installation directory.

[I wrote the detailed answer here !](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42895977/1605761)